# Websockets- send binary data as chunks

Tags: java, websocket

It is posssible to send binary data as chunks in websockets.?

I am using below code to send binary data,
**Future f = session.getAsyncRemote().sendbinary(bytebuffer);**

This transfering data as whole. So can anyone suggest me how to send data as chunks asynchronously or its there any java libary to implement this concept.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the RemoteEndPoint interface. It is documented in the class javadoc : "Implementations may choose their own schemes for sending large messages in smaller parts." (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.html).

Answer (score 1):

`WebSocket` class in [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) has methods to send fragmented frames. The following code (found in README.md) shows how to send a text message ("How are you?") which consists of 3 fragmented frames. You can send fragmented binary frames in a similar way.

```java
// The first frame must be either a text frame or a binary frame.
// And its FIN bit must be cleared.
WebSocketFrame firstFrame = WebSocketFrame
    .createTextFrame("How ")
    .setFin(false);

// Subsequent frames must be continuation frames. The FIN bit of
// all continuation frames except the last one must be cleared.
// Note that the FIN bit of frames returned from
// WebSocketFrame.createContinuationFrame() method is cleared,
// so the example below does not clear the FIN bit explicitly.
WebSocketFrame secondFrame = WebSocketFrame
    .createContinuationFrame("are ");

// The last frame must be a continuation frame with the FIN bit
// set. Note that the FIN bit of frames returned from
// WebSocketFrame.createContinuationFrame methods is cleared,
// so the FIN bit of the last frame must be set explicitly.
WebSocketFrame lastFrame = WebSocketFrame
    .createContinuationFrame("you?")
    .setFin(true);

// Send a text message which consists of 3 frames.
ws.sendFrame(firstFrame)
  .sendFrame(secondFrame)
  .sendFrame(lastFrame);
```

Or, alternatively, the same as above can be done like this.

```java
// Send a text message which consists of 3 frames.
ws.sendText("How ", false)
  .sendContinuation("are ")
  .sendContinuation("you?", true);
```

**JavaDoc**

http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/

**GitHub**

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

**Blog**

WebSocket client library (Java SE 1.5+, Android)
  http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html