# how to send an image in a webSocket request using postman

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, postman

I am new to socket.io and want to send images using postman in a WebSocket request. I have searched for it but could not found any reasonable answer. I have attached the SS of my postman request.

Following is the server-side listener code for the socket.io

```js
$socket->on('send-message', function ($data) use ($io, $socket) {

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'token' => 'required',
        'socket_id' => 'required',
        'receiver_id' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|file|image'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return $io->emit('error', json_encode(['message' => $validator->messages()]));
                    
    return $io->emit('success', json_encode(['message' => 'image uploaded successfully']));

});
```

Comment: I may be wrong but that should not be possible. In fact socket.io just provides a way to send bytes through a socket but does not offer any way to interpret those. That said you have some alternatives: use base64 for your file and decode it, serialize it so you can read bytes directly in your server. You won't be able to use your server code as is.

Comment: you shouldn't send big amount of data with WebSockets

Comment: As per the comments above, you can encode your image (binary) to a base-64 string and send it by pieces (chunks), except [you shouldn't send large amount of that via WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925975/1019059). 

You could send just the URL of the previously uploaded media instead.

Comment: @Mujeeb where is your SS of postman req....?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* send the image as [binary data frames](https://javascript.info/websocket#data-transfer):

> WebSocket .send() method can send either text or binary data. "socket.send(body)" allows body in string or a binary format, including Blob, ArrayBuffer, etc. No settings required: just send it out in any format.

So basically:

```
WebSocket.send(000100101010000010011100.....)
```

BUT - a far simpler solution would be to use a [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) string, as ALL browsers [support it natively](https://caniuse.com/?search=Base64):

```
WebSocket.send('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU .......')
```